# How to resolve an Invalid JSON primitive model error?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I am passing form data using the following assignment in an ajax post call:

```
data: {model: JSON.stringify(formData) },
```

The `model` parameter is used to tell the stringify method to parse the form data as the same type model ties to the view.

But when I return a JSON bool value to the ajax method, I get a `JSON primitive model is invalid` error stemming from a 500 Internal server error. I think this is also causing my `success function` in the ajax code from firing.

*Question:*
How do I resolve an invalid JSON parameter error on returning a bool value?

**The ajax method:**

```
var formData = $("createForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "CreateEscalation")',
                data: {model: JSON.stringify(formData) },
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json.Success) {
                        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#submitStatus').text("Error occurred while processing your request, please try again or contact system administrators");
                        $(this).addClass('alert alert-danger fade in');
                        $('#submitStatus').show();
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {


                }

            });
```

**Controller post method:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Escalation escalation)
    {
        try
        {


            bool success = sqlConnection.InsertWebReq(escalation);


            if (success)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "EscalationHistory"),
                    Success = true
                });

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    Success = false
                });

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Success = false
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and use `data: formData,` and you model will be correctly bound.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var formData = $("createForm").serialize();
```

Does not create valid JSON for MVC to consume.
(https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js)

Excerpt:

> Why not .serializeArray()?
>
> JQuery's .serializeArray() works a bit different. It makes this structure from markup in "Arrays of objects/nested objects" example:

```
[
    { "person.friends[0].email" : "agent.smith@example.com" },
    { "person.friends[0].name" : "Smith Agent" },
    { "person.friends[1].email" : "n3o@example.com" },
    { "person.friends[1].name" : "Thomas A. Anderson" }
]
```

Secondly you're double encoding:

```
var formData = $("createForm").serialize();  // First encode

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "CreateEscalation")',
            data: {model: JSON.stringify(formData) },  // Encoding Again ?
```

So you're JSON is prety much garbage because it'll look like:

```
{
  'model' : 'asdf=1&qwer=2'
}
```

or

```
{
  'model' : '{ asdf:1, qwer:2 }'
}
```

Comment: So what your saying is, use serializeArray() in place of .stringify() and that will solve the return error?

Answer (score 0):

An unwrapped boolean value is not allowable per strict JSON specifications, which require all primitives to be passed within an array or object "wrapper".  Many JSON serialization/deserialization libraries do add support for unwrapped primitives, but you should not count on this behavior unless you specifically know that both the server and client libraries support this.

My suggestion would be to wrap the result in an object like `{"result": false}` or `{"result": true}`

Comment: What would be an example of a wrapped bool in my case? I tried wrapping the success bool in my json result in quotation marks but got a syntax error.

Comment: @BrianJ An example would be exactly like what I have shown in my answer.  Or if you wanted to wrap in an array could be `[true]` or `[false]`. No need to put quotes around your actual boolean value (doing so would make it a string rather than boolean primitive) as JSON supports this primitives. It just has to be within an object or array context to meet JSON specification.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple and removing the extra parameters like `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and not double encoding solved the issue as Erik above identified.

The following Ajax method definition worked for me in the finish up:

```
                $.ajax({
                        url: "@(Url.Action("Index", "CreateEscalation"))",
                        type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: $("#createForm").serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //todo: use result
                        if (result.Success) {
                            window.location.href = result.redirectUrl;
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#submitStatus').text("Error occurred while processing your request, please try again or contact system administrators");
                            $(this).addClass('alert alert-danger fade in');
                            $('#submitStatus').show();

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

I thin the error is in  `data: {model: JSON.stringify(formData) }` it should be 
 `data: { 'model': JSON.stringify(formData) }`